# Colors on the webpage

Tags: web, responsive-design, color-scheme

Does exist any study, article or whatever which speak about using colors on page which are related to some specific topic? For example if you making pages about food, etc. 
I'm finding something like "webpage color design standard" - which will say this X number of colors are too much this. 
So I'm finding some general rules which are used in webdesign focused on colors on page and their meaning and impact on mood of visitors. 
I could compared it to this rule: We usualy use sans-serif font for webpresentation and serif for printing version, because of advantages while the user reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great tutorial on colour schemes etc
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/design-theory/an-introduction-to-color-theory-for-web-designers/

This is a study based on the human eye and colour perception, may be of some use.
http://www.blutner.de/color/colour_perception.pdf

This helps explain the psychology of colour
http://www.wix.com/blog/2013/06/color-web-design/

This article also focuses on psychology of colour
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/28/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/

This is a question on the best way to use colours
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16308/what-would-be-equivalent-blue-colour-for-this-red-orange-one

Like all psychology different people react in different ways, but this should give you an idea. I would also suggest doing a quick search ie if you are making a sports site, just searching "best colour for a sports site" can often give some good results, also look at similar/competitor sites for an idea.